# what does "hoop" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "hoop" mean in

> Had a mac for a short while and as a development machine I didn't like it. Keyboard was awful, tooling wasn't right. Too many **hoop**s. Just got the x1 now, and it's hands down amazing machine.

The dictionary shows that hoop is some circular object, which doesn't make sense here. Thanks.

Comment: See "**[jump through hoops](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jump_through_hoops)**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hoop* here is a reference to the idiom *[jumping through hoops](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hoop)*, which OALD defines as

> to do something difficult or complicated in order to achieve something

The Online Etymology Dictionary dates the expression to at least 1917, deriving from the idea of someone jumping through hoops on horseback as a circus trick, from around 1793. The *American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* similarly attributes it from the early 20th century, alluding to *trained circus animals jumping through hoops*.

Thus, a *hoop* in this sense is a difficulty or obstacle— a *[hurdle](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hurdle_1)*.

Comment: Jumping through hoops does not imply that the obstacle is meaningless, only that the entire collection of obstacles is exacting and takes a good deal of effort.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast *Meaningless* is perhaps strong, but there is a strong connotation that the steps are there mainly to satisfy bureaucracy or enforce exclusivity. You don't *jump through hoops* to become a billionaire, though that is an arduous process with many intermediate steps. But you do *jump through hoops* to get a building permit for your money bin.

Comment: Is the deciding factor that the hoops are there because _someone else put them there_? I think that when you are jumping through hoops, you are specifically performing actions which may serve someone else's purposes but provide no direct benefit in achieving your own.